# Kafka->S3->Oozie->Hadoop, Kafka writing to a S3 location, oozie read this folder every 15 mins and push the new files to hadoop

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, apache-kafka, oozie

The above title describes the workflow and I want to validate the design here, plus discuss how to manage the updates coming to shared S3 folder.

As oozie is consumer of data, and kafka is producer of data here, how do I maintain which files have already been consumed and which files are yet to be consumed, given that the producer of data is continuously writing to the location.

Are there any atomicity features provided by Amazon-s3 to maintain this?

**Update Note** : Kafka cannot directly write to HDFS because of network connectivity constraints.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're making life hard for yourself. You can just use Kafka Connect (which is part of Kafka) and the [HDFS connector](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-hdfs/docs/hdfs_connector.html) or [S3 connector](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-storage-cloud/kafka-connect-s3/docs/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am already using s3 connector to write to S3, but directly using HDFS connector is not possible in my case because of network, the data produced by kafka cannot directly be sent to HDFS, but has to go through a shared space which is S3. If possible, can you please guide me with given network constraint.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Oozie coordinator here. The oozie cordinator can poll continuously for new files and once a file has arrived, it can trigger a oozie workflow to copy copy the data. The file names/folders you can create based on the format ${baseFsURI}/${YEAR}/${MONTH}/${DAY}/${HOUR}/${MINUTE}. It will help oozie cordinator to identify the new files that has arrived.

More information is here : https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.1.3-incubating/CoordinatorFunctionalSpec.html

To set up oozie cordinator to poll for s3 files use : https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Batch-Processing-and-Workflow/Getting-Oozie-Coordinator-datasets-working-with-S3-after-a-lost/td-p/27233